# Only default values are returned in Calendar object in android. Why?

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-calendar

I have set a date to a calendar object in this way...

```
Calendar lastCheckUp = Calendar.getInstance();
lastCheckUp.set(year, month+1, day);
```

Now, when I print this out in the console using

```
System.out.println(lastCheckUp);
```

I get the correct values...

```
07-18 11:59:13.903: I/System.out(1717): java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1365834504001,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=Asia/Calcutta,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=15,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=13,DAY_OF_YEAR=103,DAY_OF_WEEK=7,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=58,SECOND=24,MILLISECOND=1,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

So i'm assuming that all the values are set correctly in the calendar object.

But when I try to access it using

```
mTextViewLastCheckDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(lastCheckUp.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            .append("/").append(lastCheckUp.MONTH).append("/").append(lastCheckUp.YEAR)
            .append(" "));
```

I get only the default values...

That is, my textview gives an output of `5/2/1`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `lastCheckup.MONTH`, `lastCheckup.DAY_OF_MONTH` etc. Those are *constant* fields - to access the values for a specific calendar, you need

```
int month = lastCheckUp.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

etc. Read the [documentation of `Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for more details about how you're meant to use it.

However, you would also need to understand that months are 0-based in `Calendar`, so it still wouldn't look right. Also, you almost certainly want to 0-pad the day and month. You'd be *much* better off using `SimpleDateFormat` to do this for you.

```
// Not sure why you want a space at the end, but...
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy ");
mTextViewLastCheckDate.setText(format.format(lastCheckup.getTime());
```

You should consider which time zone and locale you want to use, too. The above code just uses the default.

EDIT: Note that this line:

```
lastCheckUp.set(year, month+1, day);
```

is almost certainly wrong. We don't know what `month` is really meant to be here, but in the `set` call it should be in the range 0-11 inclusive (assuming a Gregorian calendar).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is how you are accessing the `Calendar`'s `get` method and your reference to `Calendar` constants.

Try this:

```
mTextViewLastCheckDate.setText(
  new StringBuilder().append(lastCheckUp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))              
  .append("/")
  .append(lastCheckUp.get(Calendar.MONTH)) // beware, Calendar months are 0 based
  // please refer to Jon Skeet's solution for a better print out of your date
  // or add +1 to the month value here, instead of setting your Calendar with month + 1. 
  // Otherwise December will not work. See also comments below. 
  .append("/")
  .append(lastCheckUp.get(Calendar.YEAR))
  .append(" ")
);
```

By the way, most IDEs will warn you when you are trying to access a class' constants from an instance of said class. 
This can help you figure out what you're doing wrong usually.

Comment: That will *not* give the results that the OP wants though - the month will be wrong.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree it requires better calendar handling. +1 for your solution. I was just pointing out how to fix the code here.

Comment: I'd argue that while it gives inappropriate values (the month number) it's still not "fixed". That's aside from the 0-padding and the preferred use of `SimpleDateFormat` - those are more arguable - but I can just see someone (anyone visiting the site, not just the OP) using your code and not immediately noticing that the month number is off by 1...

Comment: @JonSkeet again, I agree with you. However please note that OP is "fixing" this by setting the Calendar's date adding 1 to the month's value (`lastCheckUp.set(year, month+1, day);`). It's not the right way to do it, granted, but it should "work" in this instance.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited my answer to point out to the 0-based month and to your solution. Up to the OP to actually pick yours instead.

Comment: Eek - I hadn't noticed that bit. Aargh! Yes, that is indeed broken for December, I strongly suspect. Thanks for adding the comments - it's more a matter of helping future readers (who may well not read SO comments, but will hopefully read the ones in the answer).

Comment: Yes. It will break for December as OP is setting month + 1 in his calendar, so, assuming 11 + 1, the Calendar will automatically set the value to January (0).